# Press effect Android Widget

Tags: android, widget, touch, effect

I'd like to add a press/touch effect to my widget. I'm trying with something like:

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.layout_appwidget_imageButtonPrevious,
                    "setAlpha", 50);
remoteView.setInt(R.id.layout_appwidget_imageButtonPrevious,
                    "setAlpha", 255);
```

When the RemoteView is clicked. The problem is that there is a certain delay for the effect to take place and so only the second one is actually shown in the widget (so there is no visible touch effect). If I drop the second instruction I have a touch effect but it is permanent, which of course is something I don't want to have.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With an animation:

```
   iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.fade_in);

            iv.startAnimation(animFadein);
      });
```

in res/anim/fade_in.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:fillAfter="true" >

     <alpha
          android:duration="100"
          android:fromAlpha="0.0"
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
          android:toAlpha="1.0" />
     </set>
```